VBA | Find all "text" and change their font color Red
I want to find all the cells with text "Not Found", and make their font Red.
Any advise on how to do so?
String NotFound = "Not Found"
My program will call the subprocedure Find_NotFound
The Looping part Im not very sure, as it should Find until all "Not Found" are Red.
I got an Error on the "Loop While" part
Sub Find_NotFound(NotFound As String)

    '============================================
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Find_NotFound As Range
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Set Find_NotFound = Cells.Find(What:=NotFound, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    
    'Start from A1 Cell, start Finding
    '===================================================================
    'If found "Not Found" word
    If Not Find_NotFound Is Nothing Then
    
        Find_NotFound.Activate
                    
        Do
                With Selection.Font
                    .Color = vbRed
                End With
                
                Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate
            
        Loop While Cells.Selection.Font.Color <> vbRed

    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub

Kind Regards

This is a different and much faster approach that achieves the same result:
Sub ColourNotFoundRed()
    Cells.Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
        Formula1:="=""Not Found"""
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub


SELECTing cells for no reason is generally a bad idea.  The same code can be made better without using SELECT.

Please, try the next adapted code. It should be very fast, not selecting anything, placing the found cells in a Union range and color their font at one, at the end:
Sub Find_NotFound(NotFound As String)
    '============================================
    Dim Find_NotFound As Range, ws As Worksheet, strFirstAddr As String, rngRed As Range
    'Range("A1").Select 'No need to select anything. Selections only consumes Excel resources and slow down the code
    Set ws = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
    Set Find_NotFound = ws.UsedRange.Find(what:=NotFound, After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    'Start from A1 Cell, start Finding
    '===================================================================
    strFirstAddr = Find_NotFound.address
    'If not found "Not Found" word:
    If Find_NotFound Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
                    
    'find all occurrences:
    Do
        addToRange rngRed, Find_NotFound 'place the found cell in a Union range
            
        Set Find_NotFound = ws.UsedRange.FindNext(After:=Find_NotFound) 'set the next found cell
        
    Loop Until Find_NotFound.address = strFirstAddr 'otherwise, the loop will continue for ever...
    
    If Not rngRed Is Nothing Then rngRed.Font.Color = vbRed 'color the found cells at once (much faster than individually)
    MsgBox "Job done..."
End Sub

If you need/want to have only the found cells having red font you should firstly clear the font color for all used range.
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

@user2741620 Didn't you find some time to test the above adapted code? If tested, didn't it do what you need?

Another possible code, without loops.
Sub ChangeCellFormat()
 
   ' Set the CellFormat object to replace any font with red.
   Application.ReplaceFormat.Font.Color = vbRed
 
   ' Find and replace cells with "Not Found"  with red font.
   ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace What:="Not Found", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=True
   MsgBox "The font has been changed to red."
   Application.ReplaceFormat.Clear
 
End Sub

